# Swift Optionals - Syntax logic

Tags: swift, option-type, chaining

Looking at this example of conditionals I am confused. 
Here is the code and my interpretation

```
var animal = Animal(name: "Lenny", species: "lemur", tailLength: 12)
animal = Animal(name: "Gilbert", species: "Gorilla", tailLength: nil )

if let tailLength = animal.tail?.length {
    print("\(animal.name)'s tail is \(tailLength) long")
} else {
    print("\(animal.name) doesn't have a tail.")
}
```

We have a variable "Animal". Not all animals have tails and so some tailLength values will return nil.

To me, an optional is something with options - in this case it can be an Int or nil (In the case of Gilbert above).

Now, when we want to unwrap it, we are using chaining to check if it will return nil. If it returns an Int, we return it. If it returns nil, we move to the else statement.

Why is the syntax -

```
if let tailLength = animal.tail?.length
```

rather than

```
if let tailLength = animal.taillength?
```

or

```
if let tailLength = animal.tail.length?
```

*Note: New to programming. I'm aware that perhaps the answer requires some prerequisite knowledge of other languages and common syntax.*

Comment: This is called optional chaining: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: It seems the OP somewhat knows about optional chaining, and in addition to confusion regarding it wonders also why it's used it to access property `.length` of the optional `tail` property (which is a, say, `Tail` instance?) in an instance of `Animal`, _rather than_ the (also existing?) `tailLength` property of the `Animal` instance. @mutantChicken: if your question goes beyond confusion regarding optional chaining, please show us the class `Animal` as well as any custom classes that `Animal` make use of (`Tail`?)

Answer (score 2):

Let's clear this up.

First some prerequisites…

### Optionals

Optionals do not necessarily imply options. Instead, "optional" simply implies that the value may or may not exist, hence it is "optional". Think of Optionals as containers sized just right so that they may only hold one specific type. For example, an Optional created specifically to hold an `Int` could never hold a `String`, and vice versa. By this definition, Optionals sound exactly the same as variables and constants, but the big difference to note is that unlike regular variables and constants, the containers for Optionals may contain "no value at all", AKA `nil` or they may contain a value of their specified type. There are no other options.

Optionals are used anytime it makes sense for there to be no value at all, since `nil` is a better representation of "nothing" than say, -1 for an Integer.

For example,

```
class Contact {

    var name: String
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var emailAddress: String?

    init(name: String, number: String?, emailAddress: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.phoneNumber = number
        self.emailAddress = emailAddress
    }

}
```

This is a vastly simplified version of what you might use to represent an entry in a contacts app. For simplicity, we'll use `String`s to represent each of these properties. The question mark after the type name means that we do not want these properties to be of type `String`, but instead `String?`, or "Optional String". The app requires the user to enter their name, but the user may or may not choose to provide a phone number or email address, so the corresponding properties are declared as optional Strings. If the user provides an email address, for example, then the emailAddress property will hold a `String` representing the address. If the user had not provided an address, the emailAddress property would not hold a `String` but instead `nil`, or the absence of a value.

Behind the scenes, an Optional is just an enumeration with two cases: None, and Some with a wrapped value of the type the optional was declared. If you're not familiar with Swift enumerations or this is confusing to you, please ignore this paragraph. It is not important in order to understand Optionals.

**Optionals always have only two options. Either `nil` or a value of the type they were declared.**

### Unwrapping Optionals

Now suppose we want to access an Optional at some point. We can't just reference it because there is a possibility that it could be `nil` and our calculation wouldn't function properly. For example, if we wanted to access the user's email address, we might try something like

```
let user = Contact(name: "Matt", number: nil, emailAddress: nil)
sendEmail(user.emailAddress)
```

Assuming that the `sendEmail` function requires a `String` representing the address as an argument, Swift will report an error and not let the code compile as is. The problem is that we cannot guarantee that there will actually be a `String` to pass `sendEmail`. `sendEmail` requires a `String` but we are trying to pass it a `String?`. **These are not the same type.** If we know that the value will indeed exist, we can just append an exclamation mark **immediately after** the value that is optional. So, continuing with our example,

```
let user = Contact(name: "Matt", number: nil, emailAddress: nil)
sendEmail(user.emailAddress!)
```

Here, the exclamation mark tells Swift that we are sure there will be a value in the `emailAddress` property, so Swift goes ahead and converts the `String?` to a `String` with the value. If at runtime it turns out that `emailAddress` evaluates to `nil`, we will get a fatal error. Of course, in this case, we will get a fatal error at runtime because `emailAddress` did indeed contain `nil`.

Much of the time, however, and especially in our `Contact` example, we will not be able to guarantee that a emailAddress exists. Now introducing Optional Binding…

### Optional Binding

For times when we simply do not know whether a value exists, but would like to use that value for something if it does, we can use Optional Binding.

Suppose we want to send the user an email if they provided their address. Well, we would need to ensure the value is not `nil`, assign it to a constant if it isn't, and do some workaround if it is. Here's a perfectly valid way of doing so:

```
if user.emailAddress != nil {
    let address = user.emailAddress!
    sendEmail(address)
} else {
    promptForEmailAddress()
}
```

Here, we are checking to make sure the address is not `nil`. If it is, we will ask the user to give it to us. If the address does exist (if it's not `nil`), we will assign it to a constant by force unwrapping it with an exclamation mark. We can do this because if the `if` statement resolves to `true`, we can be absolutely certain that `user.emailAddress` will not be `nil`. `sendEmail` is then satisfied because `address` is of type `String` and not `String?`, since we unwrapped it first.

But because this is such a common pattern in Swift, the language defines a simplified way of doing this (Optional Binding). The following code snippet is exactly equivalent to the snippet above.

```
if let address = user.emailAddress {
    sendEmail(address)
} else {
    promptForEmailAddress()
}
```

With optional binding, you combine the assignment operation with the `if` statement. If whatever is on the right of the equals operator (assignment operator) evaluates to `nil`, the `else` clause is called and the `address` constant **is never created**. If, however, the expression on the right of the equals operator does indeed contain a value, in this case a `String`, then the `address` constant is created and initialized with whatever `String` value was stored in `emailAddress`. The type of `address` is therefore `String` and not `String?` because if the constant is created, we know it is not `nil`.

### Optional Chaining

Now, sometimes you need to access properties that are at the end of a long chain of objects. For example, suppose `emailAddress` was not a `String` but instead a special `Email` object that held several properties of its own, including a `domainName` declared as a 'String'.

```
visitWebAddress(user.emailAddress.domainName)
```

If one of these values (user, emailAddress, or domainName) was declared as an Optional, this would not be a safe call and Swift would yell at us because our imaginary `visitWebAddress` function expects a `String`, but got a `String?`. Actually, this is not even valid code because we should have a `?` after `emailAddress`. What's going on here? Well, remember that `emailAddress` was declared as a `String?`, or "optional string". Anytime we want to access a property using dot syntax on an already optional value, we must use either an exclamation mark (which forces the Optional unwrapped and returns the value which must exist) or a question mark. **Whether we choose `!` or `?`, the symbol must immediately follow the property that was declared to be Optional.**

```
visitWebAddress(user.emailAddress?.domainName)
```

This statement is syntactically correct. The question mark tells Swift that we realize `emailAddress` could be `nil`. If it is, the value of the entire statement `user.emailAddress?.domainName` will be `nil`. **Regardless of whether `emailAddress` actually is `nil` or not, the resulting type of `user.emailAddress?.domainName` will be `String?`, not `String`.** Therefore, Swift will still yell at us because `visitWebAddress` expected a `String`, but got a `String?`.

Therefore, we could use a combination of Optional Binding and Optional Chaining to create a simple and elegant solution to this problem:

```
if let domain = user.emailAddress?.domainName {
    visitWebAddress(domain)
}
```

Remember, the expression on the right side of the equal operator is evaluated first. As already discussed, `user.emailAddress?.domainName` will evaluate to a `String?` that will be `nil` if the email address was not specified. If this is the case and the expression evaluates to `nil`, no constant is ever created and we are done with the if statement. Otherwise, the value is bound (hence "Optional Binding") to a created constant `domain` (which will have type `String`) and we can use it inside the if clause.

As a side note, Optional Chaining can sometimes result in no action at all taking place when a value is `nil`. For example,

```
textField?.text = "Hello"
```

Here, if `textField` evaluates to `nil` (for example if the UI has not loaded yet), the entire line is skipped and no action is taken.

Now for your exact question,

## Code Analysis

Based on your posted code sample, this is what is likely going on. The `Animal` class probably looks something like this at a minimum:

```
class Animal {

    let name: String
    let species: String
    let tail: Tail?

    init(name: String, species: String, tailLength: Int?) {
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        if let lengthOfTail = tailLength {
            self.tail = Tail(length: lengthOfTail)
        }
    }

}
```

Now, you're probably wondering what is up with all this mention of a `Tail` object, so this is probably also existent somewhere behind the scenes, looking like this at a minimum:

```
class Tail {

    let length: Int

    init(length: Int) {
        self.length = length
    }

}
```

(Now going back and looking at `Animal` should make more sense.)

Here, we have a `Tail` object with one property called `length`, of type `Int` (not optional). The `Animal` class, however, contains a property called 'tail' which is of type `Tail?`, or "optional Tail". This means that an `Animal` may or may not have a `tail`, but if it does it is guaranteed to have a `length` of type `Int`.

So here…

```
if let tailLength = animal.tail?.length {
    print("\(animal.name)'s tail is \(tailLength) long")
} else {
    print("\(animal.name) doesn't have a tail.")
}
```

…a `?` immediately follows `tail` because it is the property that is optional. The statement `animal.tail?.length` has a type of `Int?` and if it is `nil` because `tail` is `nil`, the `else` clause is called. Otherwise, a constant `tailLength` is created and the tail length as an `Int` is bound to it.

Note that in the `Animal` initializer, it simply took an `Int?` for `tailLength`, but behind the scenes it checked to see if it was `nil` and only if it wasn't did it create a `Tail` object with the specified length. Otherwise, the `tail` property on the `Animal` was left `nil`, since `nil` is the default value of a non-initialized optional variable or constant.

Hope that clears up all of your questions on Optionals in Swift. The [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) has some great content on this, so check it out if needed.